# How to parse REST API STREAM

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, java-8

I am sending a get request to the server and server returns the following two responses. These responses are received as the event occurs on servers in streams (like id1,id2,id3,id4.....and so on) not in one shot.

Now, I need to take these response one by one and parse it and then save it the objects for further use.

How do i achieve this java 8 and spring MVC?

```
id: 1
data: {"event_type":"ABC","business_call_type":"XYZ","agent_number":"nnn","call_recording":null,"number":"0000","uuid":"a","call_direction":"Outbound","caller":"+100000000000","customer_number":"+100000000000","version":"1.0","k_number":"+917303454203","type":"AGENT_CALL","unique_id":"0","call_solution":"xx","FreeSWITCH_IPv4":"11111","Event_Date_Local":"2020-03-28 11:46:47"}

id: 2
data: {"event_type":"AGENT_ANSWER","business_call_type":"Outbound","agent_number":"+1111111111","call_recording":null,"number":"+22222222","uuid":"bbbbbbbbbbbbbb","call_direction":"Outbound","caller":"+100000000000","customer_number":"+100000000000","version":"1.0","k_number":"+1111111111","type":"AGENT_ANSWER","unique_id":"bbbbbbbbbb","call_solution":"xx","FreeSWITCH_IPv4":"0.0.0.0","Event_Date_Local":"2020-03-28 11:47:00"}
```

Comment: Have a look at RestTemplate
https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Comment: Hi David,this a async in natures and run in the baground.Please find by below code which i have written for getting the reponse body but i didnot get any respose in the received in the logger.Please review the code in answer  and suggest @DavidPi

Answer (score 1):

below is the code used foe above json parsing.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.client.AsyncRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult;

import com.psg.async_tasks.controller;
import com.psg.dao.CtiIntegrationdao;

// @Controller
@Service
public class ListningService {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ListningService.class.getName());
    @Autowired
    CtiIntegrationdao daoCtiInt;

    //@RequestMapping({"list"})
    @PostConstruct
    public  void   ListningReponse() {
        HashMap<String,String> results=daoCtiInt.getKnolarity_Config();
        String endpoint;
        endpoint=results.get("30");
        endpoint=endpoint.replace("<<AUTH>>",results.get("26"));
        logger.info(endpoint);
        logger.info("============================================================================================@postconstruct=========");
        AsyncRestTemplate asyncrestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
        try {
             final DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();
               ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> futureEntity = asyncrestTemplate.getForEntity(endpoint, String.class);
               logger.info("IN TRY");
               logger.info(futureEntity.toString());

               futureEntity.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> result) {
                String[] idno = result.getBody().split("\\R", 3);
                System.out.println("==================="+idno[0]);
                String responseBody =result.getBody().replaceAll("id: (\\d+)","").replace("data: ","");;
                logger.info("-----responsebody-----"+responseBody);
                logger.info("-----responsebody-----"+result.getBody());
//              logger.info("-----responsebody-----"+result.getBody().getAgent_number());
//              logger.info("-----responsebody-----"+result.getBody().getBusiness_call_type());
//              logger.info("-----responsebody-----"+result.getBody().getCall_duration());
//              logger.info("-----responsebody-----"+result.getBody().getCall_recording());
//              logger.info("-----responsebody-----"+result.getBody().getCall_solution());
//              logger.info("-----responsebody-----"+result.getBody().getCall_Type());
//              logger.info("-----responsebody-----"+result.getBody().getDestination());



            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                result.setErrorResult(ex.getMessage());
                logger.info("------------Failure Block"+result.toString());

            }
               });
        }catch(HttpClientErrorException ex) {
            logger.info(ex.getMessage());           
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```